# Are stack allocations RT?

Tags: c++, real-time, allocation

If I allocate something on the stack, is the allocation deterministic (i.e.  RT)? Allocation example:

`std::vector<double> desiredMobileState(13, 0.0);`

I mean allocating on the heap requires a system call (in the general case) which is non-deterministic hence should be banned for a RT behavior.

But what happens with stack allocations in terms of RT behavior?

Comment: It's not clear what your code snippet is for, but to be clear, vectors allocate their memory on the heap by default.

Comment: Why does allocating on the heap require a system call? Which documentation said that?

Comment: I would presume that on a non-realtime preemptive-scheduling system nothing is real-time.

Comment: @Dieter: RT = deterministic

Comment: @Ron Reba: the system is obviously assumed to be RT (ex: xenomai)

Answer (score 5):

The `std::vector` object itself is stack-allocated, but the object merely consists of pointers to a heap-allocated data array. (Of course, the C++ standard never uses the words "stack" nor "heap"; the above sentence is merely the usual implementation.) So allocating a vector with capacity 13 will almost certainly involve a heap allocation.

However,

> allocating on the heap requires a system call (whatever the system)

is not necessarily the case. Most heap allocations do not require any interaction with the system. It is true that on most systems some heap allocations require a system call (to modify virtual memory maps), so they cannot be considered real-time, but it is quite possible to imagine a non-virtual-memory-based embedded system in which applications had fixed memory allocations and malloc either hands off part of that memory or fails. [Note 1]

You could use a custom allocator which allocated memory regions from a pre-reserved pool, but in order to guarantee RT you would need to also ensure that the pre-reserved pool was memory-resident.

---

#### Notes.

1. Or you could just remember DOS/Apple; no need for a vivid imagination.

Comment: Is there a way to ensure that "enough physical memory" is available when starting an application (i.e. something like pre-reserving memory)? So as not to be buggged by all this...

Comment: @arennuit: that is dependent on your OS. But usually there is.

Answer (score 4):

This is all implementation-defined, of course, but in general the stack allocation itself is just the adding of a constant value to the stack pointer, so that is as deterministic as adding a value to an integer variable would be.

There are other operations that typically happen in concert with the stack allocation, however, which might make its timing non-deterministic.  Specifically:

- The running of a constructor routine to initialize the allocated object (and the constructor could of course do anything, depending on what the author of the class in question wrote there... e.g. it could allocate heap memory, open and read a file, go into an infinite loop, etc)
- The writing to (and/or reading from) of the newly allocated stack memory, which could cause a page fault, if that area of memory wasn't already mapped in to physical RAM.
- And, of course, there is always the possibility of a stack overflow, which might cause a segmentation fault (if you're lucky), or just random undefined behavior and chaos (if you're not so lucky).

Answer (score 2):

Actually stack allocation also might require system call, your thread stack might have reserved address range, but actual memory might not be yet commited. Once your code will try to use stack memory for some array request for physical memory might fail.

So to be super safe - you would have to use only static arrays, if thats what you want. From what I know some embeded system prohibit usage of malloc/free.

Comment: I am not sure I understand why you would not get the same problem with memory requests when allocating an array...

Comment: You can use static memory allocation - it is done during compile time, and if your system is low on memory then you app will simply not execute instead of failing during execution. Of course, you could achive similar thing by preallocating dynamic memory on application start.